# run several instances simultaneously and be sent periodically with rest api in java

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, resttemplate, rest

in my program (1) I have to make  RESTAPI connection to my other program(2) that is up on this url :http://localhost:8085
In my first program I have started several threads that are generating every 5 seconds like this :

```
  while (true){
  Example dto = new Example();
  Thread thread = new Thread(dto);
            thread.start();
             Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Now I want to periodically sends these threads over that connection and my program (2) should receive threads and do some analysis there.

How can I pass threads with rest template in (1) and how can I receive threads with( objectmapper.readValue )   in (2)
please help me do that . Thanks a lot

Comment: Thread class cannot be serialized. Please go through the following question ![](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622438/java-thread-serialization-why-serialized-thread-object-can-be-started) .

Comment: I want several instances to run simultaneously and be sent periodically to Program 2 . how to do it ? @Mohammad

Answer (score 0):

`Thread` is not `Serializable` and you should not try to serialize it to send over REST.

I recommend you to make some `REST API` on the first program side to return details about running threads to the outside world. Your second program will query this `REST API` and get serialized domain objects with a necessary information to make analysis.

Comment: can you please explain a little more ?I want to rest from 1->2

Comment: I want several instances to run simultaneously and be sent periodically to Program 2 how to do it ?

Comment: 1. I recommend you to work with multithreading using https://projectreactor.io or using CompletableFuture

2. Create spring service to handle requests like that

@Service
public class ThreadService {

    public void runTask(Runnable runnable) {
        //....
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        //....
    }
}

3. Create rest controller that use this service

Comment: in simple case you can expose your  status like string or create class with some fields